# How do you tell which module is preventing access to a node in Drupal?

Tags: drupal

In Drupal 8, when accessing a node page from a user who should be able to access the node, I'm getting an "unauthorized to access this page" error. We have a few different modules that restrict/allow access, but I'm unable to pinpoint which is preventing access. How can I debug this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable the modules from drupal one by one which you suspect and check the permission of the page after disabling each module which might get you to the module that is responsible for the issue then after you can debug that particular module.